# Lightning SLDS stylesheets on visualforce SITE

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, lightning-design-system, slds

I have an issue with styling visualforce page that will be exposed as a site with lightning SLDS stylesheets.

I'm using `lightningStylesheets="true"` on my page and if I preview it in salesforce context everything works fine and my VF page is styled correctly.

But when I use this page as a Site to expose it publicly it doesnt have lightning styles.

Any advice how to apply lightning styles to visualforce page exposed as a site?

Comment: have you tried using [apex:slds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm) instead?

Comment: Yeah and it works. But it would force me to redo whole page is consist of apex:inputFields and apex:pageBlock (basically whole page is done with that) which are not working with apex:slds so I'm trying to find some faster solution